# How to remove JSESSIONID cookie on session invalidation

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am testing an application with Postman, but I am not able to get a successful (`200`) response. The response code says unauthorized (`401`) and it does not return anything in the body. But cookies and headers are being returned in the response.

My colleagues, who are using the same part, are able to run this without any error.

I am not sure what is wrong with my Postman, and I don't know why `JSESSIONID` is being returned in the cookies since I am not using jsp or servlet.

Below are the attached images of the problem:

- Response cookie
  [image]
- Response headers
  [image]

Comment: Please post the picture directly in the question, not as a link

Comment: Good to know thanks @Michael, my apologies jyoti, I modified the post

Comment: It seems that your credentials as part of the request (email and password) are wrong or not present in the database. Because of that, you are getting `401 Unauthorized` response. **If you pass correct credentials, it may return `200 OK` response** assuming the API is implemented correctly (since it is working for your colleagues). And about `JSESSIONID`, it will be there if the API is in Java.

Comment: Actually, it's much better to not post images at all, if it's possible.. and in your case, it's possible. You could just include the textual information and explain it.

Comment: please don';t forget that postman is very coupled with google chrome. so maybe try an incognito postman session or be shore to delete your cookies/cache.